# Where can I get C++ Apache QPID Client library build instructions (only client)?

Tags: c++, build-process, rabbitmq, qpid

Where can I get C++ Apache QPID Client library build instructions, **no  server needed**? (as simplified as possible) (in order to use it with RabbitMQ as simple **good** AMQP C++ library)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately RabbitMQ uses an older version of AMQP than is supported by the Qpid c++ messaging library (RabbitMQ supports 0-9-1, the messaging library supports 0-10 and more recently has added 1.0 support).

You can't build the client on its own at present. Depending on what OS you use there may also be pre-built packages available. (E.g. on RHEL or fedora you can install simply the client packages without the broker).